# Reverse Cuthill-McKee algorithm: Unmatched results in Matlab and boost implementations

Tags: c++, algorithm, matlab, matrix, boost

I write a code for eigenvalue problem. During the work I needed a Cuthill-McKee algorithm for some symmetric matrices. I have a test code on Matlab and I wish to write this implementation on С++.

However, I ran into the following problem: Matlab and boost results for some matrices were not matched. For example, test on boost-site

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/graph/example/cuthill_mckee_ordering.cpp

```
#include <boost/config.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/cuthill_mckee_ordering.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/properties.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/bandwidth.hpp>


void r_cuthill_mckee(std::vector<int> &cm_ord)
{
    using namespace boost;
    using namespace std;
    typedef adjacency_list<vecS, vecS, undirectedS,
        property<vertex_color_t, default_color_type,
        property<vertex_degree_t, int> > > Graph;
    typedef graph_traits<Graph>::vertex_descriptor Vertex;
    typedef graph_traits<Graph>::vertices_size_type size_type;

    typedef std::pair<std::size_t, std::size_t> Pair;
    vector<Pair> edges = {
        Pair(0,3), //a-d
        Pair(0,5),  //a-f
        Pair(1,2),  //b-c
        Pair(1,4),  //b-e
        Pair(1,6),  //b-g
        Pair(1,9),  //b-j
        Pair(2,3),  //c-d
        Pair(2,4),  //c-e
        Pair(3,5),  //d-f
        Pair(3,8),  //d-i
        Pair(4,6),  //e-g
        Pair(5,6),  //f-g
        Pair(5,7),  //f-h
        Pair(6,7)   //g-h
    };  


    Graph G(10);
    for (int i = 0; i < edges.size(); ++i)
        add_edge(edges[i].first, edges[i].second, G);

    graph_traits<Graph>::vertex_iterator ui, ui_end;

    property_map<Graph, vertex_degree_t>::type deg = get(vertex_degree, G);
    for (boost::tie(ui, ui_end) = vertices(G); ui != ui_end; ++ui)
        deg[*ui] = degree(*ui, G);

    property_map<Graph, vertex_index_t>::type
        index_map = get(vertex_index, G);

    std::cout << "original bandwidth: " << bandwidth(G) << std::endl;

    std::vector<Vertex> inv_perm(num_vertices(G));
    std::vector<size_type> perm(num_vertices(G));

    //reverse cuthill_mckee_ordering
    cuthill_mckee_ordering(G, inv_perm.rbegin(), get(vertex_color, G),
        make_degree_map(G));

    cout << "Reverse Cuthill-McKee ordering:" << endl;
    cout << "  ";

    cm_ord.reserve(10);
    for (std::vector<Vertex>::const_iterator i = inv_perm.begin(); i != 
    inv_perm.end(); ++i)
        cm_ord.push_back(index_map[*i]);
    cout << endl;

    for (size_type c = 0; c != inv_perm.size(); ++c)
        perm[index_map[inv_perm[c]]] = c;
    std::cout << "  bandwidth: "
        << bandwidth(G, make_iterator_property_map(&perm[0], index_map, perm[0]))
        << std::endl;
}


int main()
{
    std::vector<int> cm_ord;
    r_cuthill_mckee(cm_ord);
    //cm_ord is [0 8 5 7 3 6 4 2 1 9] 

    for (auto ic : cm_ord)
        std::cout << ic << " " << std::flush;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

is matched with Matlab symrcm-function. How I understood this:
I generate a 10x10 zero matrix with elements on positions (with one-based indexing, of course) equal to 1, because symrcm-function works with both symmetric and nonsymmetric matrices:

```
A = zeros(10,10);

A(1,4) = 1;
A(1,6) = 1; 
A(2,3) = 1;  
A(2,5) = 1;  
A(2,7) = 1;  
A(2,10) = 1; 
A(3,4) = 1; 
A(3,5) = 1;  
A(4,6) = 1; 
A(4,9) = 1;  
A(5,7) = 1; 
A(6,7) = 1; 
A(6,8) = 1; 
A(7,8) = 1;

[i,j] = find(A);
bandwidth1 = max(i-j) + 1

p = symrcm(A)
%p - 1 = [0     8     5     7     3     6     4     2     1     9]
B = A(p,p);

[i,j] = find(B);
bandwidth2 = max(i-j) + 1
```

For Matlab (zero-based indexing):

```
input_bandwidth = 0 (why?)
output_bandwidth = 4

[0  8  5  7  3  6  4  2  1  9]
```

For boost C++:

```
input_bandwidth = 8
output_bandwidth = 4

[0  8  5  7  3  6  4  2  1  9]
```

However, another test like this (C++ code):

```
#include <boost/config.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/cuthill_mckee_ordering.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/properties.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/bandwidth.hpp>


void r_cuthill_mckee(std::vector<int> &cm_ord)
{
    using namespace boost;
    using namespace std;
    typedef adjacency_list<vecS, vecS, undirectedS,
        property<vertex_color_t, default_color_type,
        property<vertex_degree_t, int> > > Graph;
    typedef graph_traits<Graph>::vertex_descriptor Vertex;
    typedef graph_traits<Graph>::vertices_size_type size_type;

    typedef std::pair<std::size_t, std::size_t> Pair;
    vector<Pair> edges = {
        Pair(0, 0),
        Pair(0, 7),
        Pair(1, 1),
        Pair(1, 5),
        Pair(1, 8),
        Pair(1, 12),
        Pair(2, 2),
        Pair(2, 4),
        Pair(2, 9),
        Pair(2, 11),
        Pair(3, 3),
        Pair(3, 6),
        Pair(3, 10),
        Pair(3, 13),
        Pair(4, 4),
        Pair(4, 9),
        Pair(4, 11),
        Pair(5, 5),
        Pair(5, 8),
        Pair(5, 12),
        Pair(6, 6),
        Pair(6, 10),
        Pair(6, 13),
        Pair(7, 7),
        Pair(8, 8),
        Pair(8, 12),
        Pair(9, 9),
        Pair(9, 11),
        Pair(10, 10),
        Pair(10, 13),
        Pair(11, 11),
        Pair(12, 12),
        Pair(13, 13)
    };  


    Graph G(14);
    for (int i = 0; i < edges.size(); ++i)
        add_edge(edges[i].first, edges[i].second, G);

    graph_traits<Graph>::vertex_iterator ui, ui_end;

    property_map<Graph, vertex_degree_t>::type deg = get(vertex_degree, G);
    for (boost::tie(ui, ui_end) = vertices(G); ui != ui_end; ++ui)
        deg[*ui] = degree(*ui, G);

    property_map<Graph, vertex_index_t>::type
        index_map = get(vertex_index, G);

    std::cout << "original bandwidth: " << bandwidth(G) << std::endl;

    std::vector<Vertex> inv_perm(num_vertices(G));
    std::vector<size_type> perm(num_vertices(G));

    //reverse cuthill_mckee_ordering
    cuthill_mckee_ordering(G, inv_perm.rbegin(), get(vertex_color, G),
        make_degree_map(G));

    cout << "Reverse Cuthill-McKee ordering:" << endl;
    cout << "  ";

    cm_ord.reserve(14);
    for (std::vector<Vertex>::const_iterator i = inv_perm.begin(); i != inv_perm.end(); ++i)
        cm_ord.push_back(index_map[*i]);
    cout << endl;

    for (size_type c = 0; c != inv_perm.size(); ++c)
        perm[index_map[inv_perm[c]]] = c;
    std::cout << "  bandwidth: "
        << bandwidth(G, make_iterator_property_map(&perm[0], index_map, perm[0]))
        << std::endl;
    }


int main()
{
    std::vector<int> cm_ord;
    r_cuthill_mckee(cm_ord);

    for (auto ic : cm_ord)
        std::cout << ic << " " << std::flush;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

(corresponding Matlab code):

```
A = zeros(14,14);

A(1, 1) = 1;
A(1, 8) = 1;
A(2, 2) = 1;
A(2, 6) = 1;
A(2, 9) = 1;
A(2, 13) = 1;
A(3, 3) = 1;
A(3, 5) = 1;
A(3, 10) = 1;
A(3, 12) = 1;
A(4, 4) = 1;
A(4, 7) = 1;
A(4, 11) = 1;
A(4, 14) = 1;
A(5, 5) = 1;
A(5, 10) = 1;
A(5, 12) = 1;
A(6, 6) = 1;
A(6, 9) = 1;
A(6, 13) = 1;
A(7, 7) = 1;
A(7, 11) = 1;
A(7, 14) = 1;
A(8, 8) = 1;
A(9, 9) = 1;
A(9, 13) = 1;
A(10, 10) = 1;
A(10, 12) = 1;
A(11, 11) = 1;
A(11, 14) = 1;
A(12, 12) = 1;
A(13, 13) = 1;
A(14, 14) = 1;

[i,j] = find(A);
bandwidth1 = max(i-j) + 1

p = symrcm(A)
%p - 1 = [7     0    12     8     1     5    11     9     2     4    13    10     3     6]

B = A(p,p);

[i,j] = find(B);
bandwidth2 = max(i-j) + 1
```

gives unmatched results.

For Matlab (zero-based indexing):

```
input_bandwidth = 1
output_bandwidth = 4

[7  0  12  8  1  5  11  9  2  4  13  10  3  6]
```

For boost C++:

```
input_bandwidth = 11
output_bandwidth = 3

[13  10  3  6  11  9  2  4  12  8  1  5  0  7]
```

Please, help me, because a lot depends on this algorithm in my solver.

I have read many books on this subject but didn't find anything appropriate.

Of course I can implement it yourself, but I don't want to do what I already have.

Comment: And what bandwith you get with Matlab and your boost program for same matrix?

Comment: Is the MATLAB code correct? Can you show us more C++ code? It's hard to spot bugs with no algorithm code. Could it be a problem with row-major vs. column-major indexing between the two algorithms?

Comment: I changed my question with your comments. Column-major and row-major  indexing aren't important here, because when I compile edges of my graph, there is no difference between (i,j) and (j,i).

Answer (score 0):

The answer I think is hidden in the help of MATLAB (and is not documented in the docs)
According to the description in the help of symrcm it works well for symmetric matrices, if S is non- symmetric MATLAB calculates symrcm(S +S'). This is the case in both your examples